# Drywall in a bathroom cabinet?

Tags: bathroom, drywall, moisture

I have mosture drywall in my bathroom and I have a 3’x 3’ linen cabinet do I need to use moisture Barrier  drywall in there I have a lot of normal sheet rock I can use ? Does it really matter in there

Answer (score 2):

Use what you've got, with a good mold-resistant bathroom paint.

In theory, if the bathroom is very humid and you don't have (or use) a window or an exhaust fan you might benefit from buying more greenboard .... but ... if it's *that* humid you probably can't have a linen closet there anyway.  Everything in it will be moldy.   So basically, if you have moldy towels you have bigger problems.  And if not, you don't need to add to your drywall stockpile.